# How to get template Link in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

If I create template-portfolio, how do I get the link of this template? Like:

```
<a href="<?php the_link"> View portfolios </a>
```

What would be the function or link here?

Comment: did you saw my answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Here how you can get your theme URL :

```
<a href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/page-url/"> View portfolios </a>
```

**Note :** /page-url/ will be the URL of the page you create(Permalink). You need to assign the page to the template-portfolio. (see right side bar, Page attributes)

You can copy and use the hole permalink, but it will be an absolute path which is not recommended.

**Edit :** Your template portfolio needs to begin like this :

```
    <?php
/**
 * Template Name: Template Portfolio
 *
 */
```

If you add a new page now you can see the template and you can have the URL to it.

Answer (score 0):

get_template_directory_uri() 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/

are you searching something like this?

Comment: I don't understand what you want